# Is streamlit safe to build dummy web apps

Tags: python, web, analytics, streamlit, data-security

I was making a web app using streamlit and thinking of using as presentation, but I am unsure about the data file that I upload using `st.file_uploader()`,does this data gets stored in streamlit servers or cloud or does it stays in the local system only? The data is sensitive and must not be shared anywhere.

Is it safe to upload the data using `st.file_uploader()` when I am running the site from terminal.

So I run the web app from terminal using `streamlit run Main.py`, and then I upload the data file from my local system. I am expecting that this data gets stored in my RAM only and not on some cloud storage of streamlit.

Also there is concept is streamlit cache, where does this gets stored?

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in RAM according to the [doc](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/using-streamlit/where-file-uploader-store-when-deleted). They are removed from memory, I quote, when:

- The user uploads another file, replacing the original one
- The user clears the file uploader
- The user closes the browser tab where they uploaded the file